# How can I log full commit messages in git?

Tags: git

**Background**

I'm trying to log the differences between my **dev** and **master** branch in git. What I'm interested in seeing is only the commit messages. I want this log to be written in one line.

What I have tried:

```
git log --left-only --graph --cherry-pick --oneline dev...master
```

**This gives me the following output:**

[image]

**The problem**

I'm not seeing the **entire** commit message. For instance, if I change the flag `--oneline` to `--pretty=full`, I get a bunch of other information I'm not interested in. However, I get the full commit message at least.

**The example below is how the third commit from the screenshot above looks like when I change `--oneline` to `--pretty=full`:**

[image]

As you can see, the commit message here includes an issue number to our JIRA issues.

**Question**

How can I display all commits in a one line manner like in my first screenshot, but show the ENTIRE commit message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git log --left-only --graph --cherry-pick --pretty="%H %B" dev...master
```

- `%H` stands for the full version of sha1 value. If you find it too long, `%h` is optional.
- `%B` stands for the subject and the body, equivalent to `%s%b`.

For more placehoders, see https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Comment: Freaking lovely. Thanks